# requests works fine in my local ubuntu but does not work in AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pip, python-requests

Following is the code.  (python3)

```
import requests

url = "https://www.clien.net/service/group/clien_all?&od=T33"
response = requests.get(url)

html = response.text
print(html)
```

This code works perfect in my local ubuntu.

When I run it in AWS EC2, it fails with the error (requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.)

When I tried a different url ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)), both my local ubuntu and AWS EC2 ubuntu work good.

Thus, I am thinking that the url (https://www.clien.net/service/group/clien_all?&od=T33) works in somewhat mysterious way, and it is handled good by my local ubuntu pc, but not handled good by my AWS EC2 ubuntu server.

I thought that probably the pip environment may be different.

I did pip freeze > requirements.txt  in my local pc, and then did pip install -r requirements.txt in my AWS EC2, but still the same problem continues.

What do I have to do to make the AWS EC2 work?

Thanks

=========================
As Daniel advised, I tried curl in EC2.  It shows the following error.

[image: EC2 curl output image]

Comment: What do you get if you `curl -v https://www.clien.net/service/group/clien_all?&od=T33` from the EC2 instance? Is it different from running curl locally?

Comment: @DanielScott  Yes, they are different.  Local curl displays whole html file, whereas EC2 curl shows following comment.    I updated the post to show the EC2 curl response.